# How to automatically shut down ARM server on Oracle Cloud's free tier when reaching 10TB limit?

Tags: server, cloud, rate-limiting, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-cloud-functions

I currently have a small problem that I would like to solve.
My small mail server is on the free tier of Oracle Cloud. I would like to set a PTR, but need access to support for it... so Pay as you Go.

Now I would like to avoid additional costs though, as it is just a small hobby project. I don't get along with the metrics of the cloud. Partly I see negative transfer rates and the like.

Could someone explain me a way how my ARM server shuts down automatically... should it ever reach the free 10TB due to an attack or misconfiguration. Would love to switch to the pay version with a safety net to reach support, but just not much more.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: what store are you using to be specific? Boot Volume, object store? Also I don't think the limit it 10TB on any of them

Comment: @Shiva network traffic